# How to publish a console application with COM interop and trim unused code

Tags: .net, com, publish, com-interop, self-contained

I have a simple console application that references a small third-party [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) interop .NET assembly.

I want to trim unused code when publishing.

[image]

However, when I run the trimmed published application, I get an error:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: File name:
> '3rdPartyInteropLibrary, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
> at ClassLibrary1.Class1.Print()    at Program.Main()

Even when I manually copy the *3rdPartyInteropLibrary.dll* file to the output folder I get the error.

How can I configure trimming so that it only trims my code and leave the external library untouched?

---------------------------------
.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Interop.bpac">
      <HintPath>Interop.bpac.DLL</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var printer = new bpac.Printer();
        var printers = printer.GetInstalledPrinters() as Array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trimming-options?pivots=dotnet-8-0#framework-features-disabled-when-trimming (BuiltInComInteropSupport)

Comment: I've seen it and I have no idea what action should I take to make it work.

Comment: Difficult to say much more with so little information in the question

Comment: What information is missing? Can't think of any detail that I could include that would help. The question is simple.