How to expose REST API (minimal API) in a console application?
I have a console application which must expose a HTTP API.
How do I add the ASP.NET Core's Minimal API to a console application?
Ideally without unnecessary dependencies to stuff like controllers, razor views, etc.

It seems that WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args) is supposed to be called from web application:
csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

but I want the console application to use Microsoft.NET.Sdk because

I want to deploy as a windows app, not web app and changing SDK changes also publish options
I want the console app to be lightweight. Web SDK brings in too many dependencies (>100MB output)


Its just the used Sdk for the project its does not tell anything about the output type of the project. Just set it to console.

If you have Visual Studio you can make a: "ASP.NET Core Web API" project.

Changing SDK changes too many things. I dont want the Web SDK or web project for reasons mentioned in the question


I want to deploy as a windows app,

You can add the framework reference to the shared framework as the docs suggest:
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>

Which will allow you to use/run ASP.NET Core functionality in any kind of application (note that ASP.NET Core is already a console app by itself so possibly you can just use the appropriate template). Though it should not handle your second requirement:

I want the console app to be lightweight. Web SDK brings in too many dependencies (>100MB output)

Consider looking into trimming options which can allow reducing the size of the application (and with Native AOT support for ASP.NET Core 8 it should become better and better).
See also:

Guide to trimming ASP.NET Core


Unfortunatelly, I reference 3rd party COM interop library and trimming is incompatible with COM interop, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78206352/how-to-publish-a-console-application-with-com-interop-and-trim-unused-code

So the only option to use minimal api is to reference the maximal framework?

@Liero basically yes. Again, trimming should reduce the binary size at least to some extent.

Trimming would be awesome if it worked
